# Custom properties on React Native Views

Tags: react-native

I'm writing a library and I want to add custom properties to existing React Native views, which will be handled by my library. So for example

```
<View my_custom_property=“something”>
    <TextView my_custom_property=“something_else”>Hello</TextView>
</View>
```

And I would like my objc library to access the `UIView` or `RCTView` to which this property is being applied to. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the best solution I could come with. I make use of `findNodeHandle` to pass an identifier for an element down to my `RCTBridgeModule`, and then use the `RCTUIManager` to get a `UIView`.

In my index.ios.js (or wherever you want to get access to the element), I'll create a reference to my element, and pass the ID of that element by calling `findNodeHandle` on to my bridge module.

```
var React = require('react-native');
var { findNodeHandle } = React;
const MyCustomBridge = React.NativeModules.MyCustomBridge;

var TestFairy = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    MyCustomBridge.something(findNodeHandle(this.refs.instructions));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <Text style={styles.instructions} ref="instructions">Hello</Text>
    );
  }
});
```

Then in `RCTMyCustomBridge.m`, I'll convert that ID received from `findNoderHandle` into a UIView using `RCTUIManager#addUIBlock`. What's important is that you invoke that method on the right thread, so I use the `RCTUIManager#methodQueue` and invoke `dispatch_async`.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(something:(nonnull NSNumber *)reactTag) {
    dispatch_async(_bridge.uiManager.methodQueue, ^{
        [_bridge.uiManager addUIBlock:^(__unused RCTUIManager *uiManager, NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *viewRegistry) {
            UIView *view = viewRegistry[reactTag];
            if (view != nil) {
                // Do the magic!
            }
        }];
    });
}
```

Hopefully this is useful to someone trying to access the underlying `UIView` of a React Native element. It's not exactly what my initial question was asking for, however, its a roundabout way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: I do the same thing. But sometimes the UIBlock won't execute until the next user interaction after this function was called. Have you met before?